# How to read data from usb port in android when transfer type is Isochronous

Tags: android, usb

- I am using external hardware that will transfer sound data to android device.
- In this device total 3 interface are there. among 3 only 1 interface contains endpoint that endpoint type is USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_ISOC.
- For me claimInterface is success  then i am trying to read data using bulkTransfer, but reading is failed (-1).
- I am using android > 5.0 OS

Is anyone have idea?It will be helpful for me. thanks.